# onclick of radio button go to url

Tags: php, html

I want to link  the onclick event of the radio button to the new web page.
The web pages are developed in php and syntax is as follows

```
echo """<input class="radio" type="radio" name="alg_Type" id="HP" value="HP" onclick="location.href='highP.php'"/>  <label class="choice" for="HP">High precision</label>""";
```

and I get the following error
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';''

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: JFGI - Seriously... https://www.google.com/search?q=php+echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="alg_Type" id="HP" value="HP" onclick="location.href=\'highP.php\'"/>  <label class="choice" for="HP">High precision</label>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're grossly misusing quotes. Try:

```
<?php 
  //some code
  ?>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="alg_Type" id="HP" value="HP" onclick="location.href='highP.php'"/>
  <label class="choice" for="HP">High precision</label>
  <?
  //more php code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
echo '<input class="radio" type="radio" name="alg_Type" id="HP" value="HP"  onclick="location.href=\'highP.php\'"/>  <label class="choice" for="HP">High precision</label>';
```